# Vue 3 - inject() can only be used inside setup() or functional components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am using the `PrimeVue` component library and I try to call `useToast()` from inside my own custom composition function but it is throwing me this error:

> [Vue warn]: inject() can only be used inside setup() or functional components.

Here is my composition function:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { useToast } from 'primevue/usetoast'

export function useAxiosInterceptors() {
    const addResponseInterceptors = () => {
        axios.interceptors.response.use(
            (error) => {
                if (error.response?.status == 401) {
                    showErrorToast(
                        'Session expired',
                        'It looks like you do not have a valid access token.'
                    )

                    return Promise.reject(error)
                }
        )
    }

    const showErrorToast = (summary, detail) => {
        const toast = useToast() // <-------- this causes  the error

        toast.add({
            severity: 'error',
            summary: summary,
            detail: detail,
            life: 3000
        })
    }

    return { addResponseInterceptors }
}
```

I use this composition function in my `main.ts` file.

```
import { useAxios } from '@/services/useAxios'

const { configureAxios } = useAxios()

configureAxios()
```

Answer (score 4):

`use` composables are primarily intended to be used directly inside `setup` function. It's possible to use some of them outside, but this is decided on per case basis depending on composable internals.

The error means that this one appears to use provide/inject and so intended to be used strictly inside component hierarchy, and it's incorrect to use it any where else. Since toasts are displayed by `Toast` component, the application should be instantiated any way in order to do this.

In this case Axios interceptor could be set inside a component as soon as possible, i.e. inside `setup` function of root component.