# Routes.js call function from composable

Tags: laravel-8, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am working on my `routes.js` and I want to check if user has access to module before redirecting them by calling the function `hasAccess()` from a composable but it's giving me this warning:

> [Vue warn]: inject() can only be used inside setup() or functional components.

routes.js

```
import { createWebHistory, createRouter }   from "vue-router";
import useFN  from "./composables/FN"

const routes = [
    // define routes here
]

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes,
})

const { hasAccess } = useFN()  // use function from composable

router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
    console.log(await hasAccess());  // call function from composable
    next()
}

export default router;
```

How can I call a function from composable if I don't have setup()?

Answer (score 1):

Usually I don't have any issues using composables I create for my self as they are usually very basic, but according to [Vue 3 - inject() can only be used inside setup() or functional components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71883241/vue-3-inject-can-only-be-used-inside-setup-or-functional-components?rq=1)
composable your composable appears to be using provide/inject which is intended within a setup() method

I will like to propose another approach if viable.
You could call a method(action), getter inside your store instead, if you are using one.

I often use that perform checks before navigating to a route for example if a user account is suspended or the authenticated user does not have the intended privilege

````
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import store from '@/store'

...

const account = {
  'ACTIVE': 1,
  'RESTRICTED': 2,
  'DECLINED': 0
}
const routes = [
      {
        path: '/some-path',
        component: () => import('../components/...'),
        props: route => ({ reference: route.query.reference }),
        meta: { requiresAuth: true },
        beforeEnter: async (to, from) => {
          if (store.getters['Auth/authUser'].account_status == account.RESTRICTED) {

            return false
          }

          return true
        },
      },
    ...
    ]
    ```
````